# iphone : proplem with table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsexception

I have a problem with table view in iphone .. i can't figure out why it crashes everytime 
will here is the code

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [self checkAndCreatePList];
    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];

    self.animals = [plistDict objectForKey:@"Animals"];



         [super viewDidLoad];

}



    -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier =@"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    if(cell== nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier]autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [animals objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}
```

it's crashes at the line 
cell.textLabel.text = [animals objectAtIndex:row];
and tells me that 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: what is the content of file at pListPath?

Comment: Try NSLogging `[animals objectAtIndex:row]`, if it's wrong, try NSLogging `self.animals`, if that's wrong, use: `NSLog(@"%@", [plistDict]);`. Use this to backtrace what's wrong in the storage. The code seems ok to me.

Comment: IS animals is an array or  dictionary

Comment: Oh, and is `pListPath` the link to a NSDictionary?

Comment: ok thanks every one for your fast help.. it seems that i need some sleep here.. but before that.. can anyone give me a link to how to make a table with let's say some categories and under every category we have list of string from the plist for example.. i hope it's easy  for you thanks again you saved my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Animals` key in your plist refers to a dictionary, not an array.  Dictionaries don't have a guaranteed order, so asking for an object at a particular index doesn't make sense.

In addition to this, you have a memory leak - `plistDict` is allocated but never released.  Have you run the static analyser over your code?

Answer (score 0):

`[plistDict objectForKey:@"Animals"];`

is returning a Dictionary not an Array like you are expecting. You need to check out your plist file to see if the data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

the error seems that you are calling `objectAtIndex` on a NSDictionary object at line cell.textLabel.text = [animals objectAtIndex:row]; check what does animal contains at run time. For this use NSLog before this line. NSLog(@"%@",animals);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `animals` is some `dictionary` and you are calling `objectAtIndex:` method on it. `objectAtIndex`: is `NSArray` method.